# Error in opening Python executable file, created using cx_freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze

Before asking this question have checked other queries ([cx_freeze ImportError when executing file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553439/cx-freeze-importerror-when-executing-file)) was related to my issue, error was "DLL load failed" but my case is "No module named".
My question is - I have created a Python executables using cx_freeze but when I open the Main.exe file, the application opens with Traceback errors on it..

```
    import sys
    from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

    # Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
    build_exe_options = {
        "optimize": 2,
        "includes": [],
        "compressed": True,
        "copy_dependent_files": True,
        "create_shared_zip": False,
        "append_script_to_exe": True,
        "include_in_shared_zip": False,

        "include_files":[('vPlot.ui'),
                         ('vPlot.py'),
                         ('company.jpg')], 
        "include_msvcr": True,
        "packages": [],
    }

    # GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
    # console application).
    base = None
    if sys.platform == "win32":
       base = "Win32GUI"

    setup(  name = "plcTest",
            description = "plcTest!",
            options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
            executables = [Executable("Main.py",
                                      base=base,
                                      copyDependentFiles=True,
                                      appendScriptToExe=True)])
```

my error is (https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1oLc.png), I can't find the file "'matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg'", please give your advise, thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you put `'matplotlib'` in the 'packages' list? If it still doesn't work, please show the output from freezing it (with a pastebin link).

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, it worked big time again, thanks for the help again and again. Just one small changes " "packages": [('matplotlib')]," in the setup.py made a big difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cx-freeze have good module analysis but sometimes it is fails. Especially back and modules.

Matplotlib uses *tkagg* (i am not sure it is package name)as backend gui module. To solve this, you have two options;

1- import missing package somewhere in your code

2- pass package name to cx-freeze as parameter.

Example: i used cx-freeze from command-line

```
cxfreeze FooMain.py --include-module=simplejson, lxml  # FooMain.py my main script
```

edit: using python build_exe_options

```
"packages": ["simplejson", "lxml"],
```

Comment: thanks for the effort, you have asked me do the command-line to force the package name, how to find the cxfreeze xx.py (the path please)

Comment: i modified for script use. But, you should sure package name that u need.

Comment: Thanks @cengizkrbck have imported the missing package and bundled when generated, now its working fine, thanks for the effort

Comment: your welcome. i am suffered to much from freezing problems :)

Comment: @Java.beginner what is the missing package's name? it will be good for others.

Comment: on the above code i just added "packages": ["matplotlib"], then it stared freezing. I think when you include matplotlib, it automatically detects and packs everything together, I guess...  Thanks for your help...